# How to set image and text in Message Body of MFMailComposerDelegate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a Mail Controller i had attached a image in mail controller 
Now i want to add a text below this image.
I tried to set Message Body but text comes above image.
Next i tried to do 
 and  but it cant works.
I want to add text "Sent via Application Name"
Please Help 
Thanks in Advance

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [controller setSubject:@"App Name"];
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    UIImage *img=dataObj.images;
    NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png"  fileName:@"Default.png"];

    NSString *abc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sent via App Name"];


    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
NSString *abc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sent via App Name"];
[controller setMessageBody:abc isHTML:no];
```